# Lock screen orientation in non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-layout

i want lock screen orientation in non-Activity static class, like this

```
public class ScreenUtil {

private static Context context;

public static void Init(Context context) {
    ScreenUtil.context = context;
}

public static boolean lock() {
    if (((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) ||
    ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

but on lock method Eclipse want to cast context to Object

```
((Object) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and still want change cast

my question is if i cant change orientation like this(in static non-Activity class) and how if its possible fix it

thanks for all answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Activity reference as a parameter to your init method

```
private static Activity context;

public static void Init(Activity context) {
    ScreenUtil.context = context;
}
```

Then you can use

```
context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: fine, but what if i want Init in only one Activity(MainActivity).?

Comment: and that what u wrote can be write other way :) `public static boolean lock(Activity context) {`